# linq, group by and count

Tags: c#, linq, count, linq-group

I have a list of Unions with several members and another table with page hits by Union.
Need a report that list each union, the number of each type of member and the clicks (page views).

clicks are on a separate table with a date and unionID

this is close but doesn't really have the results I want. The count shows the total of members but not the total of clicks. How do i get the total clicks? (count records in clicks table that match the UnionID)

```
(from c in db.view_Members_Details
 join h in db.tbl_Clicks on c.unionID equals h.unionID 
 group c by new { c.UnionName, h.unionID } into g
 select new
 {
     TotalClicks = g.Count(),
     UnionName = g.Key.UnionName,
     userTypeID1 = g.Where(x => x.UnionName.Equals(g.Key.UnionName) && x.userTypeID.Equals(1)).Count(),
     userTypeID2= g.Where(x => x.UnionName.Equals(g.Key.UnionName) && x.userTypeID.Equals(2)).Count(),
     userTypeID3= g.Where(x => x.UnionName.Equals(g.Key.UnionName) && x.userTypeID.Equals(3)).Count(),
 }).ToList();
```

results should be:

```
Clicks Count |  Union Name | userTypeID1 Count  | userTypeID2 Count  | userTypeID3 Count |
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the first condition in your WHERE, because you're already grouping on the `UnionName`.

```
g.Count(x => x.userTypeID == 3) //etc for 1, 2, 3
```

As for the clicks, try the following:

```
TotalClicks = g.Count(x => x.unionID == g.Key.unionID)
```

Comment: thanks, removing the 'where' works good but the TotalClicks doesn't work. It just adds up all the records so it count the number of member and number of click all together. I would need them separate